# Defining method in java

Tags: java, methods, user-defined-functions

Let's say, 5 is considered a good number. A method is to define to check a number is good or not. Parameter type `int` and return type is `boolean`. If argument is 5 it will return true and false otherwise.

See this code:

```
class Library{
    boolean isGood(int num){
        return num==5;
    }
}

public class String_handling {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int num=8;
       System.out.println(new Library().isGood(num));
    } 
}
```

I know this code is okay.

But I want to define a method such that I can invoke in this way:

```
System.out.println(num.isGood());
```

As work on string like this:

> MyString.contains("xy");
>
> MyString.substring(0,4);

Is there any way? Give an example.

Comment: No. `int` is a primitive, and there are no methods on primitives. Also, note that `contains` and `substring` are defined on the `String` class - they aren't custom methods that you can add dynamically.

Comment: To add to what @AndyTurner said. You cannot use *wrappers* for primitives as well because they are `final` and can't be extended

Comment: *"Is there any way?"* As long `num` is your `Library` and not `int` like in this code snippet, then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `int` is a primitive, the only way you can to that, is to make your own class `MyInteger` and add your method isGood(), like so

```
public class MyInteger{

    private int num;

    public MyInteger(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public boolean isGood(int num){
        return this.num == num;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. I made some modifications and forgot to edit that. Fixed.